# Don't know how to create a centered "image + text" watermark in pdf files with iText (Java)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, itext, watermark

I'm using the iText library, and I'm trying to add a watermark at the bottom of the page. The watermark is simple, it has to be centered an has an image on the left and a text on the right.

At this point, I have the image AND the text in a png format. I can calculate the position where I want to put the image (centered) calculating the page size and image size, but now I want to include the text AS text (better legibility, etc.).

Can I embed the image and the text in some component and then calculate the position like I'm doing now? Another solutions or ideas?

Here is my actual code:

```
try {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("example.pdf");
        int numPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("pdfWithWatermark.pdf"));

        int i = 0;
        Image watermark = Image.getInstance("watermark.png");
        PdfContentByte addMark;

        while (i < numPages) {
            i++;
            float x = reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i).getWidth() - watermark.getWidth();
            watermark.setAbsolutePosition(x/2, 15);
            addMark = stamp.getUnderContent(i);
            addMark.addImage(watermark);
        }
        stamp.close();

    }
    catch (Exception i1) {
        logger.info("Exception adding watermark.");
        i1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd go looking for a text-to-png solution (java.awt.Graphics.drawString() ?) and use a graphics API to put the 2 together.

Comment: The point is that I don't want to put the text in PNG format, I need to put it in "text mode".

Answer (score 1):

you better check this:

```
import com.lowagie.text.*;
import java.io.*;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.*;
import java.util.*;

class  pdfWatermark
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {  
    try 
    {
      PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("text.pdf");
      int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();

      // Create a stamper that will copy the document to a new file
      PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, 
        new FileOutputStream("text1.pdf"));
      int i = 1;
      PdfContentByte under;
      PdfContentByte over;

      Image img = Image.getInstance("watermark.jpg");
      BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, 
        BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

      img.setAbsolutePosition(200, 400);

      while (i < n) 
      {
        // Watermark under the existing page
        under = stamp.getUnderContent(i);
        under.addImage(img);

        // Text over the existing page
        over = stamp.getOverContent(i);
        over.beginText();
        over.setFontAndSize(bf, 18);
        over.showText("page " + i);
        over.endText();

        i++;
      }

      stamp.close();

    }
    catch (Exception de) 
    {}
  }
}
```

([source](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/itext/how-to-display-watermark-in-pdf-documents-from-3.html))

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.

Answer (score 0):

is a bit ugly but, can't you add the image and the text to a table and then center it?